# Como editar dados que já foram salvos no SharedPreferences

Tags: android

Olá,

Estou fazendo um aplicativo e estou salvando algumas informações no SharedPreferences, que são informações de usuário, como por exemplo nome/telefone.

Estou fazendo um editar perfil e queria saber como faço para alterar não so no banco de dados(Como já fiz) mas tambem no sharedPreferences.

Como faço para alterar dados que já foram salvos no shared preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da mesma forma que você escreve, você apenas pode sobrescrever suas preferências atuais com o novo valor, você pode consultar esta [página](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java) para mais informações.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Entendi, eu usei uma chave para salvar as preferencias, então so reutilizei essa chave e aparentemente ele sobrescreve. Obrigado de qualquer forma!